# Jade Mixin: 500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, pug, templating

I've got a mixin causing me trouble:

```
mixin dialog(title, description, choices)
    form.choices.dialog.row
        legend
            h1 #{title}
            p.description #{description}
        fieldset
            for choice in choices
                label
                    input(type= "radio", name = "choice.name", checked = "checked", required = "required")
                    | choice.name
        div.row.form-actions
            button(type="submit", ) Make Choice
```

To call it, I first include the mixin file with this mixin:

```
import dialog
```

Then I use the mixin, after creating a javascript variable:

```
- var investiageUFODialog = [{headerText: "Would you like to investiage the UFO?", description: "Choose whether or not to investigate the UFO."}, {choices: [{name: "Yes"}, {name: "No"}]}]

mixin dialog(investiageUFODialog.headerText, investiageUFODialog.description, investiageUFODialog.choices)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`investiageUFODialog` can't be an array if you want to use it like that. Just change it to:

```
- var investiageUFODialog = {headerText: "Would you like to investiage the UFO?", description: "Choose whether or not to investigate the UFO.", choices: [{name: "Yes"}, {name: "No"}]}
```

Also, in your mixin, you need to write `name = choice.name` (without the quotes).